# How to convert a concurrent queue to an immutable queue

Tags: c#

A concurrent dictionary can be converted to an immutable dictionary like this:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string,JObject> x = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, JObject>();
public ImmutableDictionary<string, JObject> X => x.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

I'm trying to convert a concurrent queue to an immutable queue, like this:

```
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<JObject> x = new ConcurrentQueue<JObject>();
public ImmutableQueue<JObject> X => x.ToImmutableQueue();
```

However, the method `ToImmutableQueue` does not exist.

I looked over the API but I didn't see an equivalent for this method.

So, what is a way of converting a concurrent queue to an immutable queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the factory methods https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440262(v=vs.111).aspx

```
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<JObject> x = new ConcurrentQueue<JObject>();
public ImmutableQueue<JObject> X => ImmutableQueue.CreateRange<JObject>(x);
```

I suspect it's not included as an extension because FIFO queue and LIFO stack are inherently thought of as mutable data structures even with an Immutable implementation; whereas, a dictionary or a set are inherently thought of as having read-only versions.

Since the transition between ConcurrentQueue and ImmutableQueue is really a change in implementation instead of interface, then I'd think you'd lose the thread-safety of the ConcurrentQueue, so I wouldn't recommend doing this unless that is your goal.